# See someone unused environment variable

Tags: environment-variables

Let's say I log in as **Bob** to host **server**.
Then i do :

```
export MYSEC='secret'
```

Let's say Alice has access to the same host and also sudo permissions.

How can Alice see the value of MYSEC?

Note : let's say Bob never closes the session so the value remains there and we allow Alice to work

Answer (score 1):

Alice dumps memory of the shell process that Bob has running, opens the dump in a hex editor, looks for MYSEC, then looks at value.

Used vs Unused has no bearing.

Comment: Awesome. Can you elaborate on how to do the memory dump?

Answer (score 1):

Scraping memory is *waaaaaay* overcomplicating things.  Just look in `/proc/<pid>/environ`, for any `<pid>` owned by `bob` in which he set the environment variable of interest, and out it'll drop.  The entries in that file are NULL-separated by default; for display purposes, `cat /proc/<pid>/environ | tr '\0' '\n'` is suggested.

Comment: That works for any _child_ of the shell where bob exported the var (if the child lives long enough to look at) but not the shell itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for anyone interested in how to do this :

Alice logs in and searches for the PID of Bob's Bash session.

Let's say is 34232.

Then Alice makes a memory dump of this as :

```
gdb -p 34232
gcore memory_dump.bin
quit
```

Now open the file with **vim** and search for the name of the variable. It is repeated several times. Just hit **n** until you find it.